# Как установить значение из базы в dropDownList?

Tags: yii2

в форме _form.php есть поле dropDownList:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList([
            'Ок' => 'Ок',
            'Не ок' => 'Не ок' ])
?>
```

при загрузке формы в поле устанавливается пустое значение, даже если в базе есть иное.
Как сделать так чтобы по умолчанию в поле автоматом подгружалось установленное значение из базы?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте `var_dump($model);` В начале страницы, и сразу будет ясно, что не так.
Проблемы с выгрузкой модели или с параметрами DropDownList.

Убедитесь, что `$model->status` не пустое значение. И что его значения совпадают с ключами указаными в массиве:

`[
   'Ок' => 'Ок',
   'Не ок' => 'Не ок'
]`

Вашы значения должны быть `'Ок'` или `'Не ок'`, так как вы указали в параметрах.

Comment: похоже я напутал с параметрами в базе, спасибо за наводку.